# Cordova slower then mobile Chrome even with Crosswalk plugin

Tags: android, performance, cordova, webview, html-framework-7

after days of days googling and trying all possible solutions found on internet I still have problem with my Cordova project. All my tests I'm doing on real Android device.

Using latest Cordova 8.0.0 (cordova-android@7.0.0) with no plugins, basic configuration. I created very simple single page Framework7 app, with no content, just blank white page with blank side panel.

When opening side panel I can notice significant lag in opening animation. Same issue when using Crosswalk plugin. Also tried downgrade Cordova few version below but still no lucky. Same issue with Gradle versions from 4.4 to 4.7. Tried also hardwareAccelerated "true" and "false", with "false" lag even worse.

Interesting is that when I open my application in mobile Chrome everything works like a charm, smooth and fast. I thought that Cordova is using that same WebView as mobile Chrome. So performance should be the same.

Using navigator.userAgent in Chrome Console on my PC with connected device I can confirm that both WebView versions in mobile Chrome and Cordova are same "Chrome/66.0.3359.126".

Any help and suggestion what to next? Or how to fix this problem?

Thanks!